# HTML&JS validation for select tag

Tags: javascript, html

**Is it possible to know whether the user clicks the select list**
**There should be a validation of select list in this image**

[image]

I need to use Javascript to have this error-msg function of select list and validation of select list which needs to be filled. Anyone could help me, I am very appreciated

This is code below

```js
 function validation(thisForm) {
  
//validation of fName
    if(!thisForm.fname.value.length)
    {
      document.getElementById('fname-error').style.display="block";
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById('fname-error').style.display="none";
    }
        //validation of lName
    if(!thisForm.lname.value.length) //if there is no input to lName
    {
      document.getElementById('lname-error').style.display="block";
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById('lname-error').style.display="none";
    }
    if(!thisForm.address.value.length)
    {
        document.getElementById('address-error').style.display="inline-block";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('address-error').style.display="none";
    }
    var patt=/[^0-9A-Za-z\s/-]+/g; //collection of invalid input characterset
    var addr = thisForm.address.value;
    if(patt.test(addr)==true)
    {//we found a validation
        
        document.getElementById('address-error').style.display= "none";
    }
    else
    {
        
        document.getElementById('address-error').style.display= "inline-block";
    }
    
    
    if(!thisForm.dob.value.length)
    {
        document.getElementById('dob-error').style.display="inline-block";
        
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('dob-error').style.display="none";
    }
    
    
    
    if(!thisForm.fname.value.length || !thisForm.lname.value.length|| !thisForm.address.value.length||!thisForm.dob.value.length)
    {
      return false
    }
    return true;
}
```

```css
 .error-msg {
  display: none;
  color:red;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 120px;
  margin-left: 10px;

}
```

```html
    <form action="#" onSubmit="return validation(this);">

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Application Name</legend>
      <div class="name">
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
        <span class="error-msg" id="fname-error">First name is required</span>
      </div>

      <div class="name">
        <label for="lname">Last Name </label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" size="50">
        <span class="error-msg" id="lname-error">Last name is required</span>
      </div>
            <div class="address">
        <label for="address">AddressLine 1</label>
        <input type="text" id="address" name ="address">
        <span class="error-msg"id="address-error">address error</span>
            </div>
      <div class="dob>
        <label for= "dob">dob</label>
        <input type ="date" id="dob" name="dob">
        <span class ="error-msg" id="dob-error">dob error</span>
      </div>
      <div class="state">
        <label for="select">State</label>
        <select id="state" selected="" value="Default">
          <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
          <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
          <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
          <option value="SA">SA</option>
          <option value="WA">WA</option>
          <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
          <option value="NT">NT</option>
          <option value="TAS">TAS</option>  
        </select>
      </div>
       
    </fieldset>
    
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
```

Comment: why don't use required ? ex: `<select id="state" selected="" value="Default" required>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check for the `value` of `select` to see if there `selected` option has any value. If there is no value we will throw the `error` else we will just continue.

**Edit:** As you highlighted you do not want to use required attribute i have updated my answer to do the validation with `Java-script` only.

**Live Demo:**

```js
function validation(thisForm) {

  //validation of fName
  if (!thisForm.fname.value.length) {
    document.getElementById('fname-error').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('fname-error').style.display = "none";
  }
  //validation of lName
  if (!thisForm.lname.value.length) //if there is no input to lName
  {
    document.getElementById('lname-error').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('lname-error').style.display = "none";
  }
  if (!thisForm.address.value.length) {
    document.getElementById('address-error').style.display = "inline-block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('address-error').style.display = "none";
  }
  var patt = /[^0-9A-Za-z\s/-]+/g; //collection of invalid input characterset
  var addr = thisForm.address.value;
  if (patt.test(addr) == true) { //we found a validation

    document.getElementById('address-error').style.display = "none";
  } else {

    document.getElementById('address-error').style.display = "inline-block";
  }


  if (!thisForm.dob.value.length) {
    document.getElementById('dob-error').style.display = "inline-block";

  } else {
    document.getElementById('dob-error').style.display = "none";
  }

  if (thisForm.state.value == '') {
    document.getElementById('state-error').style.display = "inline-block";

  } else {
    document.getElementById('state-error').style.display = "none";
  }



  if (!thisForm.fname.value.length || !thisForm.lname.value.length || !thisForm.address.value.length || !thisForm.dob.value.length) {
    return false
  }
  return true;
}
```

```css
.error-msg {
  display: none;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 120px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" onSubmit="return validation(this);">

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Application Name</legend>
    <div class="name">
      <label for="fname">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
      <span class="error-msg" id="fname-error">First name is required</span>
    </div>

    <div class="name">
      <label for="lname">Last Name </label>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" size="50">
      <span class="error-msg" id="lname-error">Last name is required</span>
    </div>
    <div class="address">
      <label for="address">AddressLine 1</label>
      <input type="text" id="address" name="address">
      <span class="error-msg" id="address-error">address error</span>
    </div>
    <div class="dob">
      <label for="dob">dob</label>
      <input type="date" id="dob" name="dob">
      <span class="error-msg" id="dob-error">dob error</span>
    </div>
    <div class="state">
      <label for="select">State</label>
      <select id="state" name="state">
        <option selected disabled value="">Please select</option>
        <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
        <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
        <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
        <option value="SA">SA</option>
        <option value="WA">WA</option>
        <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
        <option value="NT">NT</option>
        <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
      </select>
      <span class="error-msg" id="state-error">State error</span>

    </div>

  </fieldset>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: @tonychen  See my answer all working with JS as well.